# Realtime snapshotView mirror/broadcast

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, wkwebview

I am creating an app which uses an external monitor connected to the iPad. I therefore don't make use of simply mirroring the screen, the monitor shows specific elements which do not appear on the iPad. Meanwhile I still have to mirror two WKWebViews to the monitor to both show the views on the iPad and the monitor at the same times and be able to control them using the iPad. How can I do this as efficient as possible from a performance standpoint?

What I am doing at the moment is saving an UIImage using takeSnapshot() in an ObservedObject 30 times per second. This works (not with videos and documents but for most websites) but obviously is quite inefficient for performance.

How can I achieve this without taking up the systems performance completely? Is there a way of displaying a second view rendering exactly the same content as another view in realtime?

Best regards

Comment: Have you checked ReplayKit APIs to see if there's any method provided by Apple to help you with this?

Comment: @rakappdev Have not found a solution with this. It seems as if ReplayKit and a monitor don't work together